# Не загружается фотография на бд

Tags: php

Код PHP/HTML, не грузит фото на бд(базу данных)

p.s переменная u_image существует в базе данных
p.s2 Тип данных на бд - longblob

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

if (isset ($_POST["u_upload"])) {
  $u_image = $_POST["u_image"];

    if (empty($u_image)) {
        echo "You Didn't Uploaded The Image<br />";
    }
    else {
    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `users` (`u_image`) VALUES ('$u_image')");
        echo "You Sucessfuly Uploaded The Image !<br />";
    }
}

if ($login == 0) {
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=login.php'>";
}
else {
  $u_id = $_COOKIE["uid"];
  $getinfo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = $u_id");
  $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($getinfo);
  echo '';
 ?>
<span>Name : <?php echo $arr["u_name"]; ?></span><br />
<span>Email : <?php echo $arr["u_email"]; ?></span><br />
<span>User ID : <?php echo $arr["u_id"]; ?></span><br />
<?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $arr["u_image"] ).'"/>'; ?><br />
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
  <label>Upload New Image</label>
  <input type="file" name="u_image" />
  <input type="submit" name="u_upload" value="Upload" /><br />
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` для этого не подойдет, нужно использовать `$_FILES`.

Comment: То есть только в строке $u_image = $_POST["u_image"]; нужно $_POST поменять на  $_FILES ?

Comment: Теперь пишет ошибку Notice: Undefined index: u_image in ... on line 6

Comment: `$_FILES['u_image']['tmp_name']` - вы [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php) читали? Там все об этом написано.

Comment: Короче говоря, прочитал я статью(и внёс некоторые правки), и вставил то что тут написано, нооо... ничего не работает, с той же ошибкой. Поправка, всё заработало(Не надо было мне изменять текст tmp_name), но на бд не грузит картинку

Comment: Вы пытаетесь загрузить файл или сохранить бинарку в базу? Если бинарные данные, то нужно доставать их из временного файла и после отправлять в базу, чтобы не сохранять файл на сервере. Но я вообще не понимаю, а зачем в базе хранить файлы? Файловая система работает гораздо быстрее, да и база не резиновая, так-то, в базе вы можете просто хранить хеш-код файлов, если на то пошло и использовать в виде ключа для предоставления скачивания или открытия файла.. /И у вас иньекции в коде, используйте [подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).